# AngularJS How to preload controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to access a function on my google map (MapCtrl) via '$broadcast'. This works but not unless the user has loaded MapCtrl first. How can I trick MapCtrl to load in the background so that it will hear my broadcast?

**in CouponCtrl** (where the important click is made)

```
$rootScope.$broadcast(CONST.MAP_FIND_LOCATION, id);

$state.go('tabs.map');
```

**in MapCtrl**

```
$rootScope.$on(CONST.MAP_FIND_LOCATION, function(id) {
  var slid = id;
  var smap = $scope.map;

  try{
    // var latlng = userService.locationManager.getLocationById(slid).getLatLng();
    // smap.panTo(latlng);

    var loc = userService.locationManager.getLocationById(slid);
    var address = loc.getFullAddress();

    // $scope.map.setZoom(11); directions set's the zoom automatically
    $scope.directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes:[]}); // resent display
    $scope.directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.map);

    var request = {
      origin: new google.maps.LatLng(
        userService.user.gps.coords.latitude,
        userService.user.gps.coords.longitude
      ),
      destination: address,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    }

    $scope.directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       $scope.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
     }
    });

  } catch(e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: how about adding `MapCtrl` as a dependency in `CouponCtrl` ? This way, former will always be loaded before latter

Comment: it could be easier to just pass your data along with $state.go. `$state.go('tabs.map', {location: CONST.MAP_FIND_LOCATION, id:id});` Inject `$stateParams` in your mapcontroller and access it like `console.log($stateParams.id)` or whatever you see fit. (Sidenote: Are you sure the map has loaded before using it?)

Comment: I think I would not start to stop loading things on demand. Isn't it just possible to put everything you want to do on receiving the broadcast in a function and call this function after your controller was loaded? For a better maintenance it would also be possible to create a factory around this. Just an idea; haven't done this by myself yet.

Comment: @NLN I've searched around for how this can be done but I haven't found anything promising. Did you have an implementation in mind?